# Targeting non-immediate parent in CSS for 960gs

Tags: css, stylesheet

I am using the Grid960 framework by Nathan Smith (www.960.gs) and have been for some time. On my website, I typically have the input bars take up 100% of the grid container that they are in.

However, I also nest my grid divs frequently. Here's an example:

```
<div class="grid_8">
   <div class="grid_4 alpha">
       random crap here
   </div>
   <div class="grid_4 omega">
       input boxes here
   </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to have a single location in my stylesheet where I can target an input[type="text"] within a grid_4, but if I try this:

```
.grid_8 input[type="text"] {
   width: 610px;
}

.grid_4 input[type="text"] {
   width: 270px;
}
```

It will still be 610px wide, even though the grid_4 would be a closer match. Does anybody have thoughts on how to fix something like this?

I can't just use percentages because of margins/borders/padding.

Comment: That's strange. It should be 270px, not because "grid_4 would be a closer match", but because your grid_4 rule comes after grid_8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with BoltClock's comment. If you nest grid's frequently, make sure your CSS order is actually as you show, with the smaller grid *after* the larger grid definition in the CSS (I assume you never nest a larger grid in a smaller one).

[Note the cascading order difference here that causes a width difference](http://jsfiddle.net/BTuH3/2/).

Comment: Ah, thank you. I'm self-taught in CSS so there are some basic lessons which have eluded me.